# Source code doesn't update after PHP redirection

Tags: php, redirect

good day to you, I'm currently experiencing a mysterious phenomenon that keeps me perplex and sleepless since yesterday... :/
I have a product page `site.com/product/name-product/` this page displays the correct info, and when i view the source code, all is fine.
when a client clicks on the product link from a cart page for example, it will send to `site.com/product/name-product/12345` (12345) being the product ID to show the chosen size/ color. In the beginning of the page i have the following code:

```
<?php
session_start();

$id_product = 1111;

// if the product is being viewed from the cart
if(isset($_GET['id_product'])) { // extracted from url rewriting
    $_SESSION['id_product_cart'] = $_GET['id_product'];
    header("Location: /product/name-product/", true, 301);
    exit();
}

if(!empty($_SESSION['id_prod_ref_cart'])) { // preselect size/color when viewed from cart
    $id_product = $_SESSION['id_product_cart'];
    unset($_SESSION['id_product_cart']);
}

echo $id_product;

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

The problem is after the redirection, when i view the source code, i only shows the price and data of the initial page :/

Am I missing something here?? :/

Thanks in advance for your time

Comment: Can you start session before using ??

Comment: The few facts you provide are completely disjoined. We have no idea what's happening between all these steps, how they come together, or what's happening in 90% of the relevant code.

Comment: thanks for your prompt reply :) yeah, session is already started before using...
Actually if i just remove the redirection, everything works fine

Comment: can you start session on '/product/name-product/' this page ???

Comment: @deceze: i dont know what exactly you need, the page is packed with code, but i gave the most important part of it, and i'm thinking that it's linked with the redirection, and maybe i'm just missing something stupid!!

Comment: What we know: you have some URL, you're redirecting from one URL to another, <big blank unknown>, "source code only contains price and data of initial page". – That's not really enough to help you with anything. You'll have to dig a little deeper yourself and form some more answerable question.

Comment: @deceze: I have edited my initial post putting down a full example. If i enter in the browser `/product/name-product/1234/`, it will redirect to `/product/name-product/`, displaying 1234, but in the source code, it shows 1111 :/ P.S. element inspector shows the good result 1234

Comment: If the source code that server returns is different than you are viewing in inspector, maybe you have got a javascript to manage it dinamically. True? However your `$id_product` can contains `1111` value if the script do not enter inside `if(!empty($_SESSION['id_prod_ref_cart']))` so it is logical.

Comment: No, i have no javascript, i copied/pasted all the code i have in my testing page. the page renders 1234, but when i check the **source code**, i see 1111. and the script enters inside the 2 `if()` conditions

Answer (score 1):

OMG, I think I just understood what happens!! After the redirection, when I click on "view source" in chrome, actually it doesn't simply show the code but rerun the script and so display 1111 !! Am I right?

Comment: Yeah, that sounds about right. You're really breaking HTTP conventions with that session usage. Identical requests should yield identical results; you're throwing a wrench into that by making the result dependent on the state of the session.

Comment: is there a better solution you could suggest to achieve what i'm trying to do? which is redirecting to the original url (without ID) and display info of the selected product... <br>
P.S. this is happening only with chrome, Safari works just fine!

Comment: Not without knowing what exactly it is you're attempting here. And no, please don't try to detail this here in the comments.

Comment: well, i reallt dont see how more I can explain more than what I already did :/ it's just a simple redirection to the original URL and remember what id_product to display!!

Comment: Why the redirect in the first place?! Each unique page should have its own unique URL. Redirecting to one common page whose content depends on the page visited previously is... pretty unconventional, to say the least.

Comment: as I explained before, this page shows a product that has different variations, each variation has its own ID, so when we land on the page `site.com/product/name-product/12345/` I'd like to keep the original URL to avoid the duplicate content problem. so I save 12345 in a session, 301-redirect to `site.com/product/name-product/` and then use the session variable to query the db and fetch it data...
Maybe i should keep the URL with the ID and then use canonical links?

Comment: `site.com/product/name-product?color=blue` – perfectly legitimate way to handle this problem.

Comment: but then `site.com/product/name-product?color=red` would still be considered as duplicate content!

Comment: Is this really an issue?! https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6080548?hl=en

Comment: in fact no, i was just a little URL maniac by wanting to keep them "clean". I'll opt for the query string ;)